# Compare values of different type in Lua 5.2

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to overload the == (equality) operator for `<number> == <table>` and `<table> == <number>` expressions.

However, it seems to me that Lua only uses the `__eq` metamethod when the two sides of the equation are of the same type.

For instance, the following snippet does not work as I expected

```
x = {1,2}
setmetatable (x, {__eq = function (x,y) print "!" return x[y] ~= nil end})
print (x == 1)
```

but this one does:

```
x = {1,2}
setmetatable (x, {__eq = function (x,y) print "!" return x[y] ~= nil end})
print (x == {1})
```

Is it possible to implement `==` for `<number> == <table>` and `<table> == <number>` expressions?

I'm running the latest version (5.2.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

If two objects have different basic types, the equality operation results in `false`, without even calling the metamethod.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to override equality for values of different types.

Comment: And this fact is very sad.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be feasible to patch the original Lua's implementation in order to accomplish this?

Comment: @Alistair-L., yes, it's probably a simple change in http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lvm.h.html#equalobj but you have to consider the consequences, for instance, in table indexing. You might end up with `x==y` but `t[x]~=t[y]`, clearly not desirable.

Comment: @lhf: This has always been a problem if `x` and `y` are of the same type - `rawget` looks up by object identity, not by value.